# Define links with a trailing slash /

Tags: url, seo, links, seo-lite

I have a site where all the main navigation links (Top Navigation, footer nav and html sitemap page) link to URLs without a trailing slash, however the canonical tags for all pages end with trailing slash.

Is there a way to change all the links in the main navigation to link to pages with a trailing slash, or failing that change SEO lite to define a canonical without a trialing slash?

This is my first time using ExpressionEngine.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old topic with plenty of useful information that seems to mirror your question. Hopefully this is helpful to you:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13213812/getting-the-trailing-slash-back-in-expressionengine-2

Answer (score 1):

In general, **don't try to force EE to use a trailing slash**.

Do the opposite - make the canonical links **without** a trailing slash.

Seriously, that is the way EE likes it, and you are pushing shit uphill trying to do anything else.

**Don't use a 301 htaccess redirect** - that's ridiculous, because EE generates all URLs without a trailing slash. Then you would be forcing all of your users to make two requests every time they click a link, just so you can have your way. Not a good idea :)

Best bet is figuring out how to make SEO Lite define a canonical URL without the trailing slash (I've never used it). Or just build the canonical meta tag yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way -- that I'm aware of -- to force trailing slashes within EE itself. I would hardcode the trailing slashes into your navigation where possible and failing that use a rewrite rule within your .htaccess file to force it.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

If you're using something like [Structure](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/structure) or the [Pages](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/pages/) module, SEO Lite should use the matching url from the pages array. There's an old [support thread](https://getsatisfaction.com/addonbakery/topics/canonical_url_does_not_match_pages_url) that explains the issue and subsequent updates to SEO Lite.

Comment: Any idea which file one might need to edit to make sure all main navigation links with trailing slashes?  If it is as easy as just changing a few things in a template?

Comment: When I add a trailing slash to the 'Structure Page URL' under the 'Structure' and submit, it never saves. I go back in and it's without a trailing slash again.

Comment: In the module settings for Structure there's an option to set 'Add Trailing Slash to Page URLs' to yes or no.

Comment: Right bare with me, maybe I'm being a but dim but i cant find this setting. If i click 'Structure' from the modules menu I get taken to the list of pages. Then top right is a tab 'Module settings', but there is no option for a trailing slash.

Comment: Mm, are you a super admin for the site and what version of EE and Structure are you using?